# Send pdf to folder on ftp

Tags: php, ftp

I have a form that sends to the database etc.

My question is:
Is it possible after submitting this form to work in PDF and be sent to a folder in FTP?

Which way should I take to be able to make it possible?

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With domPDF (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) you ll be able to generate a PDF from your database and save it localy.

And to save your PDF on a distant FTP, please look the function ftp_nb_put()( https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_ftp_nb_put.asp )